# Stream writing lags my GUI

Tags: c#, multithreading, streaming

I have a thread that dequeues data from a queue and write it to another application's STDIN. I'm using Stream, but with .Write and even .BeginWrite, when I send 1mb chunks to the second app, my GUI gets laggy for ~1sec. Why? My callbacks are something like this:

```
    void Progress(object sender, ProgressArgs e) {
        if (this.InvokeRequired) {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate() { Progress(sender, e); }));
            return;
        }

        progressBar1.Value = (int) e.PercentDone;
    }
```

Comment: What is the downstream process's throughput?

Comment: Have you tried using a code profiler (like products offered by Jet Brains or Red-Gate) to see what could be causing the lag?

Comment: What computer are you using?  If it's a single core, low bus speed computer, this operation could easily lag your gui (and the rest of your computer).

Comment: Core Duo 2ghz, 2gb ram.. it's normal

Comment: I've seen it in profiler and really can't explain why it lags

Comment: If you change it to write to a file, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, you're calling these callbacks too often, so that they clog your message queue with `BeginInvoke` messages. Try saving the last received percent value and calling `BeginInvoke` only when the new one is different from the last.

Comment: Good advice, but I'm sure the problem is from the .Write method because even if remove my callbacks to the gui, it still lags.